# Mercadopago - Notificaciones de aplicación con usuarios de prueba

Tags: php, api, mercadolibre

Buenas tardes, planteo mi situación aunque busqué en los grupos y no vi una igual

3 usuarios de prueba:

**El usuario A** crea una aplicación que tiene una URL de notificación (Probada y funcionando con HTTPS)

**El usuario B** acepta esta aplicación y publica en Mercadolibre un producto (Siguiendo las reglas de productos ficticios para no ofertar, etc)

**El usuario C** compra 1 ítem de la publicación del usuario B, utilizando tarjetas de prueba

En la URL de notificaciones tengo un script PHP que almacena en una base de datos el array GET y el POST con json_encode (Ambos por las dudas)
De esta forma puedo saber que datos están llegando si se notifica algo.
Si pruebo manualmente desde el navegador la URL de notificación y agrego parametros GET estos son reconocidos, no hay problema

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO ___notifications_test (ID, _date, _method, _json) 
    VALUES (DEFAULT, :date, :method, :json)
;";

$query = $connect->prepare($sql);
$bind = array(
    ':date'   => "2017-07-19 00:00:00", 
    ':method' => 'get', 
    ':json'   => json_encode($_GET)
);
$query->execute($bind);
```

**El problema es que la URL es consultada por el servidor de Mercadolibre, pero no llega ningún dato ya que GET y POST están vacíos []**

En resumen, todo está funcionando solo por el hecho de que Mercadolibre al cargar mi URL de notificaciones no está enviando ningún dato

Cual es el problema, alguien tiene idea?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola armate, tu consulta parece incompleta ya que con la información proporcionada solo se puede especular. Por favor, modifica tu consulta siguiendo esta guía _[ask]_ y si es posible agrega un __[mcve]__ que ilustre tu problema. Usa este enlace: [edit]. Recuerda que puedes dar forma a tu código usando el botón `{ }`  del editor.

Comment: Perdón pero no entiendo cual sería el dato faltante, en el ejemplo que planteo no hay código o configuración relevante. El único código PHP que interviene es un INSERT de base de datos común y corriente. La pregunta es clara, porque puede ser que llegue vacía la notificación sin GET o POST aparente

Comment: el problema principal que tenemos es que la gente de mercadopago no esta por aqui. siento decirte que te mandan aqui, pero ninguno de nosotros tiene idea de como funcionan sus API. igual tu pregunta fue cerrada antes de que agregaras el codigo. Si crees que merece una reapertura, por favor utiliza [META](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) para posturlarla para reapertura.

Comment: Todo bien gbianchi, no sabia que los de Mercadpago te mandaban acá diciendo "Nuestra comunidad" y es un terrible fake, igual sigo sin intender porque cierran el caso, aunque sea déjenlo abierto por si de casualidad alguien pasa y comenta algo o para cuando encuentre la solución yo mismo pueda postearla, realmente me parece un sinsentido que lo cierren, si bien puede haber diversas causas, el problema es concreto, llega la notificación pero vacía y describí detalladamente el escenario, no entiendo por que lo cierran realmente

Comment: pudiste resolverlo? estoy igual que vos, sospecho que es porque estoy usando un usuario de prueba, pero no estoy seguro